# How to add onClick to a tag dynamicly with function and params value function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
function myfun(par1,par2){
   //some code...
}
```

in my html

```
<a href="#" onClick="myFun('a','b')">hi there</a>
```

Well, I need remove href and onClick attr and I did it in side other function, I'd used jquery to that.

```
function towFun(){
   var var1='somVal1';
   var var2='somVal2';
   if(some condition is true){
     $('a').removeAttr('href');
     $('a').removeAttr('onClick');
   }else{
     //right there I'll need add like attr to a tag these attr again
     $('a').attr('href','#');//its OK
     $('a').attr('onClick','myFun(\''+var1+'\'\,\''+var2+'\')');**//it's not OK**
   }
}
```

What can I do with this?
Thank guys.

Comment: I dont really understand, can u post some of your html plz ?

Comment: @The_Death_Raw sorry, I have needing activate add and remor onClick event by a function... well. I did it, my problem was that I havent selector over on element , now I got solved this, Thank you to try support to me.